# SSH works until 'sudo ssh' is used, then URL gets connection refused

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have two servers connected though ethernet and with public IPs.

1. ssh from one server to the other with LAN IP : works
2. sudo ssh from the same server to the other with LAN IP : error connection refused
3. ssh from the same server to the other with LAN IP : error connection refused
4. ssh from the same server to the other with **public** IP : works
5. sudo ssh from the same server to the other with public IP : error connection refused
6. ssh from the same server to the other with public IP : error connection refused

How can I restore the ssh access ?

Comment: using sudo, uses the root users ssh keys

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` uses the root user on your machine. If you have ssh keys set up for one user, and then use `sudo`, you're now using the root user's ssh keys instead of the correct ones.

To restore access, you will need to ensure your user has the correct ssh keys set up and then just use `ssh` without `sudo`.

Comment: It figured this was the normal behaviour, although it wasn't working like this, even without using `sudo` it still didn't work.
It fixed itself after about 20 minutes though, I don't know why.